# Reasoning about (C++) memory models

Tags: c++, concurrency

I've been reading about C++ memory models and think I have a grasp of the basic concepts of happens-before, synchronizes-with and inter-thread happens-before. However, applying them in some examples has been difficult. In particular I have been thinking about the following sequence of operations when they are repeated:

```
Thread 1
1. Atomic store of X in A (seq cst).
2. Write X to B.
3. Atomic store of X in C (seq cst).

Thread 2
4. Atomic load of C.
5. Read of B.
6. Atomic load of A.
```

Now I know that following 4 Thread 2 must see the write made by Thread 1 in 2, but what happens if Thread 1 is spinning and after 3 is setting A then B and then C to Y? I think Thread 2 can see C set to X and B to Y because Thread 1 can have set A and B to Y but not set C to Y yet. This much is clear, but if Thread 2 checks A and finds it is set to X, does that mean Thread 2 must also see B set to X? I've written some code to spin Thread 1 and Thread 2 and found that if Thread 2 sees the same value for A and C then B also has the same value. I know however this does not prove it, which is the reason for this question.

I think the key thing is whether the atomic store in 1 implies anything about the store in 2? If 2 had been done before 1 then it does but that's not the case here. If the result of 2 is seen by Thread 2 before it sees the results of 1 and 3 then Thread 2 would see A and C set to X but B set to Y. Is this possible? How would that be described given the concepts above. Finally, is some other factors coming into play that may mean the program I wrote does work (on x86)?

Answer (score 2):

**Let's dissect your initial assumption:**

> I know that following 4 Thread 2 must see the write made by Thread 1
>   in 2

First example may work:

```
      Thread 1                    Thread 2 

  1. atomic store in A:  X
  2. write in B : X
  3. atomic store in C : X
                              4. atomic load of C  -> X
                              5. read B  -> X
                              6. atomic load of A -> X
```

Second example won't:

```
      Thread 1                    Thread 2 
                        initially A,B and C hold Z

  1. atomic store in A:  X
                              4. atomic load of C  -> Z
  2. write in B : X           5. read B  -> ?? (UB: can b Z, can be X, can be a mix or anything else  
  3. atomic store in C : X
                              6. atomic load of A -> X
```

Two problems happen in this example, first the load of C can occur before the write, causing the previous value to be fetched.  Second, and worse, the access of B is not guaranteed to be atomic and not protected against a race:  so you might experience UB.

**Now to your question:**

> what happens if Thread 1 is spinning and after 3 is setting A then B
>   and then C to Y ?

Let's look at a potential scenario:

```
      Thread 1                    Thread 2 

  1. atomic store in A:  X
  2. write in B : X
  3. atomic store in C : X
                              4. atomic load of C  -> X
  n. atomic store in A: Y     5. read B  -> X
  n+1. write in B: Y          6. atomic load of A -> Y
  n+2. atomic sore in C : Y
```

Again, you might not have what you've expected. Here I get Y in A but I could have got X.  I could get X in B, but I could as well have got Y or even an unexpected value in case of a race.

**Conclusion**

The *happen-before* relation within a single thread is straight forward and follows the dermined/predictible flow of control.

As soon as you have a synchronization between two threads (here the reading of atomic), the "inter-thread happen-before" is not predetermined. It depends on the point fo time of the synchronization, and must be analyzed by looking at the relative happen-before in each thread, not forgetting that immediately after other things may still change.

Finally, avoid non-atomic shared variables, unless you protect them with a lock to prevent data races.